# Помогите с '&#65279; '

Tags: php, html

Мне приходит ответ от php-обработчика известного SMS-сервиса. Но вся проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь вытянуть информацию, к ней в начало "прикрепляется" вот такой символ/ы:  "&#65279" в конце еще "; " (если пишу все вместе то в этом сообщении будет пусто). Еще он отображается как пробел.

Как от него избавится (PHP)?

Comment: ну если он у вас прямо в виде приведенного текста то и вырежете его с помощью str_replace перед какой либо последующей обработкой текста

Comment: Если он у вас в бинарном формате, можно вырезать его при помощи конструкции $str = preg_replace('/\x{feff}/u', '', $str);

Comment: спасибо за еще один вариант решение проблемы, помогло: $str = trim(preg_replace('/\x{feff}/u', '', $str));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

может есть реально другой вариант решение, но вот что я придумал:

```
   $text = trim(substr($text, 3));
```

или

```
   $text = trim(substr(iconv("CP1251", "UTF-8", $text), 6));
```

или

```
   $str = trim(preg_replace('/\x{feff}/u', '', $str));
```

вся проблема, что от них ответ приходит в CP1251, а у меня все работает на UTF-8 без ВOM-последовательности.

Answer (score 2):

Этот символ является [маркером последовательности байтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). Его нужно убрать из начала файла php-обработчика. Если обработчик на стороне сервиса - сообщите об этом техподдержке

Comment: я написал им, но сомневаюсь что они что-то изменят, спасибо за информацию.