# Посторонний символ при include

Tags: php

Делаю include

```
require 'header.php';
require "Главная.html";
require 'footer.php';
```

Но между header.php и Главная.html почему то добавляется какой-то левый html символ. В файлах ничего такого нет, даже пробелов нет. Если header пустой, то этого символа нет, стоит добавить любой символ и этот тоже появляется. Что это и как от него избавится? 
[image: incl]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сохраните файлы в UTF-8 без BOM

[Помогите с '&#65279; '](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504516/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-65279)

Comment: сохранял в UTF-8 (в sublime-text 3 это и есть без BOM) не помогло (

Comment: Ну попробуйте тогда открыть файл каким-нибудь простым текстовым редактором, который не понимает ansi или поддерживает функцию которая позволит вам посмотреть полностью исходный код и удалить этот отступ. 
Но это 100% кодировка. 
Попробуйте не просто сменить кодировку, а через notepad++ именно преобразовать в UTF8 без BOM